# QGIS on Android: Access files on Google Drive

Tags: qgis, android

I have a set of shape files that I keep updated on Google Drive.  I have just installed QGIS on an Android tablet but I can not figure out how to get access to the google drive from the file menu.

Any ideas?

Russell

Comment: QGIS may not have native Google Drive support - As a workaround, try exporting document from Google Drive by going into the Google Drive app, drilling down to the file you want, pressing the menu button and tap "Download a copy".  This should download the file to the same "Downloaded" files section, where you should be able to reach it in QGIS (can't install QGIS from the installer right now, so I can't verify this at the moment - if it works, I'll copy to answers section).